# laravel api subdomain mapping

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.3

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'api.domain.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/','TwitterController@index');
    Route::get('/gettweets','TwitterController@getTweets');
    Route::get('/viewtweets','TwitterController@viewTweets');
    Route::get('/viewvideos','TwitterController@viewVideos');
});
```

This is my routes.php

I am calling this `/gettweets` route but it says `/gettweets` is not found on server. Using godaddy linux shared. 
I am only able to call `/` requests.
How can I make laravel read this routes.

Comment: Can you tell if it was Laravel which returned the error or was it a generic Apache one?

Comment: apache is returning this error

Comment: do i have to modify the htaccess

Comment: Yeah this would happen if you didn't have the correct htaccess.  Most specifically I think it would be the MultiViews

Comment: example.com has index.html but api.example.com is hosted by laravel

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can you let me know how did you solve it?

Comment: @p01ymath, can try with `Route::domain('api.myapp.com')->group(function()
{
Route::get('/','TwitterController@index');
Route::get('/gettweets','TwitterController@getTweets');
Route::get('/viewtweets','TwitterController@viewTweets');
Route::get('/viewvideos','TwitterController@viewVideos');
})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Mod_rewrite must be enabled on your server. [***Check this post***](https://sg.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/mod-rewrite-module-NOT-loaded/m-p/6318#M5216)
2. Check you .htaccess file in public folder (which your domain pointed to) and it should contain below

   Options -MultiViews

   ```
   RewriteEngine On

   # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

   # Handle Front Controller...
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

   # Handle Authorization Header
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   ```

Create a `.htaccess` file under the public directory if it does not exists.

If this does not work leave a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify godaddy to read wildcards in a way that any subdomain points to the same point. Doing that you will manage subdomains with your laravel app

https://mx.godaddy.com/help/setting-up-wildcard-dns-3301

Comment: I have created `api.example.test` on my local machine with the help of `/etc/hosts` and Apache virtual host. How can I solve this issue?